# SUM with IF and ELSE

Tags: mysql

I would like to see the team score from a table looking like this:

Matches

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | HomeTeam  | HomeScore |   AwayTeam  | AwayScore |   Referee    |
| 1  |  Miami    |      3    |  Las Vegas  |    0      |  Tom Jones   |
| 2  | Las Vegas |      1    |      LA     |    1      |  Tom Jones   |
| 3  |  Miami    |      2    |   Orlando   |    1      |  Tom Jones   |
| 4  | New York  |      0    |    Miami    |    5      |  Tom Jones   |
| 5  |   LA      |      3    |  New York   |    1      |  Jim Bone    |
| 6  |   LA      |      0    |    Miami    |    2      |  Jim Bone    |
| 7  |  Orlando  |      2    |    Miami    |    3      |  Jim Bone    |
| 8  |   LA      |      1    |  Las Vegas  |    1      |  Jim Bone    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I dont now if you can write something like this or how you do it in mysql. But i hope you get the idea :)

```
SELECT HomeTeam, Referee, (IF HomeTeam = 'Miami': SUM(HomeScore) ELSE AwayTeam = 'Miami' SUM(AwayScore)) AS TeamScore
FROM Matches
WHERE (HomeTeam = 'Miami' OR AwayTeam = 'Miami') 
GROUP BY Referee
ORDER BY TeamScore Total
```

Result should be.

```
+--------------------------------------+
| HomeTeam  |  Referee   |  TeamScore  | 
|  Miami    | Tom Jones  |     10      |
|  Miami    | Jim Bone   |     5       |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to implement this is to use a `UNION` query to unpivot the `Home` and `Away` teams and scores into rows, and then take the `SUM` over that derived table:

```
SELECT Team, Referee, SUM(TeamScore) AS TeamScore
FROM (
  SELECT HomeTeam AS Team, HomeScore AS TeamScore, Referee
  FROM matches
  UNION ALL
  SELECT AwayTeam, AwayScore, Referee
  FROM matches
) m
WHERE Team = 'Miami'
GROUP BY Team, Referee
ORDER BY TeamScore DESC
```

Output:

```
Team    Referee     TeamScore
Miami   Tom Jones   10
Miami   Jim Bone    5
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oqo9A1ZZ2wpwSZsF6Vb5dq/2)

Answer (score 0):

you can use IF and CASE in MySQL. This is the first solution with CASE:

```
SELECT 'Miami', Referee, 
   (SUM(CASE WHEN HomeTeam = 'Miami' THEN HomeScore ELSE 0 END) +
   SUM(CASE WHEN AwayTeam = 'Miami' THEN AwayScore ELSE 0 END)) as TotalScore
FROM Matches
WHERE (HomeTeam = 'Miami' OR AwayTeam = 'Miami') 
GROUP BY Referee
```

This is the second solution with IF:

```
SELECT 'Miami', Referee, 
   (SUM(IF (HomeTeam = 'Miami', HomeScore, 0)) +
    SUM(IF (AwayTeam = 'Miami', AwayScore, 0))
    ) as TotalScore
FROM Matches
WHERE (HomeTeam = 'Miami' OR AwayTeam = 'Miami') 
GROUP BY Referee
```

Both should provide that result of what was expected in your answer:

```
Miami   Jim Bone    5
Miami   Tom Jones   10
```

I hope this helps.